# Running specific test group in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I have grouped my tests in playwright. My test grouping looks as following

```
test.describe('API Test Suite', ()=> {
test("get users @smoke", async ({request}) => {
//Test here
})

test("get countries @integration", async ({request}) => {
//Test here
})
});
```

I can grep them using tags e.g. @smoke/@integration but I wonder how can I filter them out based on their test group
i.e  "API Test Suite"
in this scenario and run them.

Comment: What stops you from using a tag inside describe title?

Comment: Yes, updating test.describe solved the problem.

Comment: Good to know it helped.I added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may directly use **tag inside describe title** as well like @API  mentioned below:

```
test.describe('@API Test Suite', ()=> {
     test("get users @smoke", async ({request}) => {
    //Test here
     })
    
     test("get countries @integration", async ({request}) => {
    //Test here
     })
    
});
```

#### Or you can simply use grep:

```
npx playwright test --grep "API Test Suite"
```

#### Or you can combine both of them to create complex scenarios:

```
//Run tests containing the @API Test Suite tag AND do not contain the @readonly tag
  npx playwright test --grep "@API Test Suite" --grep-invert "@readonly"
```