# How to run testcases with test suites in Playwright

Tags: playwright

In protractor there is the concept of "suites" (reference: https://codeburst.io/organizing-test-suites-with-protractor-ed2150718072):

```js
"test01": {
  "suites": ["smoke"],
  "user": "abc"
},
"test02": {
{
  "suites": ["critical"],
  "user": "def"
}
```

Does Playwright have a similar concept? I want to call only critical test cases.

Please let us know how to run testcases with suites in playwright.

Comment: Do you mean `test("name of suite", () => { /* the tests in the suite */ })` ([grouping](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#group-tests)), or do you mean [tagging](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. One is tagging:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

test("foo @critical", async ({page}) => {
  expect(1).toEqual(1);
});

test("bar @smoke", async ({page}) => {
  expect(1).toEqual(1);
});
```

```
$ npx playwright test --grep @critical
 
Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:3:5 › foo @critical (77ms)

  1 passed (499ms)
```

Another is grouping:

```js
test.describe("critical tests", () => {
  test("foo", async ({page}) => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
  
  test("bar", async ({page}) => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});

test.describe("smoke tests", () => {
  test("foo", async ({page}) => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
  
  test("bar", async ({page}) => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

```
$ npx playwright test --grep critical

Running 2 tests using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:4:7 › critical tests › foo (71ms)
  ✓  2 pw.test.js:8:7 › critical tests › bar (33ms)

  2 passed (479ms)
```

You can also use the `.only` method to run a single group rather than grepping:

```js
test.describe.only("critical tests", () => {
  // ...
});
```

See also [Running specific test group in Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77477307/running-specific-test-group-in-playwright/77479799#77479799).

Comment: I can't create multiple test files for critical or smoke, we can't make only one file to run critical or smoke, based on the config

Comment: "I can't create multiple test files for critical or smoke, we can't make only one file to run critical or smoke" seems like a contradictory statement. If you can't make only one file, and you can't create multiple files, either, then you're out of options. Can you clarify what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You can group tests by tagging them. Here is a solution to your question in a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77477307/running-specific-test-group-in-playwright)

Comment: The link is useful, but this seems like a comment more than an answer.